# Can't start pgadmin container on linux server

Tags: linux, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin

I'm trying to migrate project from mysql to postgres using docker and docker compose file.

I'm connected to Linux server remotely .

My docker compose file :

```
version: '3.7'
services:

  database:
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-database
    image: postgres:12
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
      POSTGRES_DB: dbtest
    ports:
      - "${POSTGRES_PORT}:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/postgres/local_pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    depends_on:
      - database
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-pgadmin4
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "${PGADMIN_PORT}:5454"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: khaled.boussoffara-prestataire@labanquepostale.fr
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 5454
    volumes:
      - ./docker/pgadmin/pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
```

My env file :

```
PROJECT_NAME=iig
PROJECT_FOLDER_NAME=sf_iig_api
HTTP_PORT=12078
HTTPS_PORT=12077
POSTGRES_PORT=12076
PGADMIN_PORT=5050
```

docker-compose ps :

[image]

I can't start pgadmin :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your compose file seems okay to me, I use different ports, but my set-up is quite close to yours.

The error message recommends "check the proxy and firewall" (vérifer le proxy et le pare-feu) ... did you check it? I would use netcat:

> nc -v -z RemoteHost Port

At least this could result in a helpful error message.